# Why is passing a char* to this method failing?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, char

I have a C++ method such as:

```
bool MyClass::Foo(char* charPointer)
{
   return CallExternalAPIFunction(charPointer);
}
```

Now I have some *static* method somewhere else such as:

```
bool MyOtherClass::DoFoo(char* charPointer)
{
    return _myClassObject.Foo(charPointer);
}
```

My issue is that my code breaks at that point.  It doesn't exit the application or anything, it just never returns any value.  To try and pinpoint the issue, I stepped through the code using the Visual Studio 2010 debugger and noticed something weird.

When I step into the `DoFoo` function and hover over `charPointer`, I actually see the value it was called with (an IP address string in this case).  However, when I step into `Foo` and hover over `charPointer`, nothing shows up and the external API function call never returns (it's like it's just stepped over) and my program resumes it's execution after the call to `DoFoo`.

I also tried using the `Exception...` feature of the VS debugger (to pick up first chance exceptions) but it never picked up anything.

Has this ever happened to anyone?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you building with Debug or Release settings?

Comment: Release settings right now (just compiled a Release ready project) I'll try debug and see if I get anything.

Comment: Did you rebuild the application completely? Maybe you're debugging an out of date binary against code you just edited?

Comment: Where does this `char*` come from? Are you sure it's properly allocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the project with Debug settings.  Release settings mean that optimizations are enabled and optimizations make debugging a beating.

Without optimizations, there is a very close correspondence between statements in your C++ code and blocks of machine code in the program.  The program is slower (often far slower) but it's easier to debug because you can observe what each statement does.

The optimizer reorders your code, eliminates variables, inlines functions, unrolls loops, and does all sorts of other things to make the program fast.  The program is faster (often much faster) but it's far more difficult to debug because the correspondence between the statements in your C++ code and the instructions in the machine code is no longer there.

Comment: Release builds also wreak havoc on the mouse-over tips for parameters and variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this would explain why it just disregards my calls.  I built in debug now and I'm getting some weird FileNotFoundException (C# is mixed with native C++ using CLI in this project) just from calling a constructor (not IN the constructor, from the constructor call) so I'll fix this and your advice will probably be able to help me fix the other issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just came back to actually explain what was going on.  Turns out the external function I'm calling was named the same as my method, so it was calling my method instead and was obviously resulting in a StackOverflow exception.  I can't believe I didn't see this, but thanks a lot for pointing out I should be in debug.